# django-tenants: Python shell with specific tenant

Tags: python, django, shell, django-tenants

I want to use "./manage.py shell" to run some Python commands with a specific tenant, but the code to do so is quite cumbersome because I first have to look up the tenant and then use `with tenant_context(tenant)):` and then write my code into this block.

I thought that there should be a command for that provided by django-tenants, but there isn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've just looked at this myself and this will work, where tenant1 is your chosen tenant:

`python3 manage.py tenant_command shell --schema=tenant1`

Comment: Yes, that works! I somehow overlooked that command..

Comment: Note that the `--schema=...` option must come *after* the command to invoke.

Answer (score 1):

I have written my own small management command for that, which needs to be adjusted to use your own tenant model:

```py
# <module>/management/commands/tenant_shell.py

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core.management import call_command
from django_tenants.utils import tenant_context

# TODO: Use your own tenant model
from core.models import Tenant

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument("-t", "--tenant", nargs=1)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if options["tenant"] is None:
            print("ERROR: please supply a tenant with the -t or --tenant option")
            return
        tenant_name = options["tenant"][0]
        # TODO: Use your own filter logic (I have a field "name" in my model)
        tenants = Tenant.objects.filter(name=tenant_name)
        if len(tenants) == 0:
            print("ERROR: tenant",  tenant_name, "does not exist")
            return
        print("Run Python shell with tenant", tenant_name)
        with tenant_context(tenants[0]):
            del options["tenant"]
            del options["skip_checks"] # TODO I don't know why this extra parameter is passed here?
            call_command("shell", *args, **options)
```

You can then run the tenant Python shell with

```bash
python ./manage.py tenant_shell -t "Tenant Name"
```

Comment: Haven't tried it but wouldn't [this](https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use.html#tenant-command) do the same if you use it with `shell`?